# Does ASP .NET c# HttpWebRequest support HTTPS Authentication via username:password@www.website.com?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, post, https

As the title says,

Does ASP .NET c# HttpWebRequest support HTTPS Authentication via username:password@www.website.com?

Almost everything I find regarding authentication appends the username and password after the website.  Will using System.Net.HttpRequest work with username and password before the website?

[EDIT]

Let me explain the scenario, this is for an application that I am developing that makes a HTTP POST to a website.  We are already using HTTPS, and the website server has my IP whielisted.  At the request of someone from the 'website', they want to use the username:password@www.website.com in addition for authentication.

Comment: that isn't a very secure method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding credentials on the url never worked for me. This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
System.Net.CredentialCache credentialCache = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
credentialCache.Add(
    new System.Uri(apiUrl),
    "Basic",
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential(basicAuthUserName, basicAuthPassword)
);

request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = credentialCache;
```

Comment: Is it simply not a possibility?  Or just a matter of setting up the post back page properly?

Comment: @chemofire: I never found why "inline" credentials didn't work for me. Since I found this snippet as the recommended way to go I just used it.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  My application is currently set up to POST to many sites that don't need credentials, and the backend isn't set up for storing credentials for each site.  So I will play around with the 'inline' method and see if I can get it to work.  I will post an answer if I find one; I was really hoping for an explanation of whether yes it works or no, and why.